# How do I position this text with simultaneous, inline, superscript and subscript?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to make a status display with 3 numbers inline with other text like so:

[image: Desired format]

-- a kind of flipped "[Isotope notation](http://preparatorychemistry.com/Bishop_Isotope_Notation.htm)".

I can do this with tables but a CSS approach is eluding me at the moment.

Ideally, I'd like to structure the HTML something like this (or simpler):

```
<p>
    <div class="sharesblock">
        <div class="shares">2535</div>
        <div class="updwncontainer">
            <div class="gains">2666</div>
            <div class="losses">-13</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    of
    <span class="companyname">Super MegaCorp</span>
</p>
```

But I can't quite make it work.  This almost does it:

```
div.sharesblock {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 3ex;
    position: relative;
}
div.updwncontainer {
    position: absolute;
    right: -2.8ex;
    top: -0.3ex;
}
div.losses {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: red;
}
div.gains {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: green;
}
```

But that absolute positioning doesn't work well with variably-sized numbers. EG:

[image: larger numbers bust it]

**Here's [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nQfx5/).**

---

**Update:**

- Oops. The above HTML does not validate. `<p>` elements are not allowed to have block-element children.
  The production code replaces the `p` nodes with `li`s.
  Tested and this does not affect the answers below, though.  They work the same irregardless.
- **[Here is the kind of testing I used to pick an answer.](http://jsbin.com/xobetoda/1)**

Comment: What's wrong with the jsFiddle example?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel, make one of the gain or loss numbers much bigger; you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Use `relatives` position and `float`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/nQfx5/4/)**

**html**

```
<p>
    <div class="sharesblock">
        <div class="shares">25355</div>
        <div class="updwncontainer">
            <div class="gains">2666666</div>
            <div class="losses">-139999</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    of
    <span class="companyname">Super MegaCorp</span>
</p>
```

**css**

```
div.sharesblock {
    margin-right: 3ex;    
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
div.sharesblock .shares{
    float:left;
    margin-right:.5ex;    
}
div.updwncontainer {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:.5ex;
}
div.losses {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: red;
}
div.gains {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: green;
}
span.companyname {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean but look at this update with ´clearfix´ class added http://jsfiddle.net/nQfx5/12/

Comment: See http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9Mks.gif .  It's a minor problem, may not be worth fussing with.

Comment: Look at the edit, is it ok this way ? I have changed the html structure.

Comment: It has the same (trivial) wrapping issue as far as I can see.  I like your first answer better, so far.

Comment: You want all the numbers to stay on the same line ?

Comment: Don't sweat it.  Your answer meets 97% of the requirement. Thank you.  Right now it's a toss between your answer and SVS's.  I'm going to sleep on it.

Comment: I like work properly done :) so 100% is the goal. Im not english so maybe I don't understand what you want. If you want the `gains` and `losses` numbers to stay next the `shares` number while resizing the window add  `min-width:150px;` into the `div.sharesblock` on my first answer. http://jsfiddle.net/nQfx5/18/

Comment: No thanks.  I want to avoid set widths (especially `px` widths!) for text elements that will have variable sizes.

Comment: Good answer, but watt's performs better. See [this side-by-side test page](http://jsbin.com/xobetoda/1).

Answer (score 0):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/nQfx5/6/)

Remove position `absolute` from `.updwncontainer` & use `float:left` property on `.shares` & `.updwncontainer`.

**CSS**

```
div.sharesblock {
    margin-right: 3ex;
    position: relative;
}
.shares {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
div.updwncontainer {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
div.losses {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: red;
}
div.gains {
    font-size: 1.1ex;
    color: green;
}
span.companyname {
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Is this what you are looking to achieve? (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/nQfx5/20/)  Feel free to add the margins you want.

By the way, [according to these guys](https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines#over-qualified-selectors), avoid `div.className` in CSS when not needed. Simply use `.className` instead.

Adjusted HTML:

```
<p>
    <div class="sharesblock">
        <div class="shares">2535</div>
        <div class="updwncontainer">
            <span class="gains">2666</span>
            <br/>
            <span class="losses">-13</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    of
    <span class="companyname">Super MegaCorp</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.sharesblock {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.shares {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding-right: 0.5ex; /* OP Added */
}
.updwncontainer {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    line-height: 1ex;    /* OP Corrected from px units */
    padding-bottom: 0.5ex;  /* OP Added to tweak alignment -- better than other solutions. */
}
.losses {
  font-size: 1.1ex;
  color: red;
}
.gains {
  font-size: 1.1ex;
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: That looks like a good solution using display:inline-block but the alignment is not right. Look at the picture

Comment: @watt It's a good idea to post your code as well as a fiddle so that there is always a reference to it :)

Comment: @BrockAdams I thought this would be what you were after. You can edit the font-size or padding of losses and gains to fine-tune the solution.

Comment: Why is `.className` better than `div.className`?

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel because that is an overqualified selector. You can read more here: [csswizardry/CSS Guidelines](https://github.com/csswizardry/CSS-Guidelines#over-qualified-selectors).

Comment: I slightly adjusted your answer; see the inline comment for how and why. After that, your approach performs the best; see [this test page](http://jsbin.com/xobetoda/1).  Thanks!

Comment: Great, I'm glad you found this solution helpful. Good luck!